# React Native Add two Side border to View does not work

Tags: react-native

I want to add Left and Bottom Border to View in React Native.

This is my code

```
dashedBorderView: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 35,
    left: 45,
    top: 50,
    right: 0,
    borderLeftWidth: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#dfdfdf',
    borderStyle: 'dashed',
  },
```

But it doesn't show any borders.

But if I do like follow, four side borders show.

```
dashedBorderView: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 35,
    left: 45,
    top: 50,
    right: 0,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#dfdfdf',
    borderStyle: 'dashed',
  },
```

Please guide me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use following property for specific border color

```
  borderLeftColor: '#dfdfdf',
  borderBottomColor: '#dfdfdf'
```

Or

```
  borderWidth: 1, 
  borderColor: '#dfdfdf',
  borderTopColor: transparent
  borderRightColor: transparent
```

Comment: Try to change  border style to solid

Comment: Tell me if it's Work.

Comment: But I want to show dashed border. And in Android does it support dashed line?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7838 thire is issue ni react native

Comment: But use can wrap your view ni another view and give him padding.so it works I hope

Comment: I tried to show solid two side border, but it doesn't show anything in ios.
In android only solid line display even though I selected dash style, but ios does not show anything.

Comment: Let me check. On ios

Comment: In which element you want to set border

Comment: It's view textinput or text